MySQL is swapping coordinates. Is this a bug?
MySQL has added a way to set SRID that should not transform the coordinates. It should only change the SRID info.
ST_SRID() changes the geometry SRID value without transforming its coordinates.
It seems to work like that:
mysql> select st_astext(point(23,56));
+-------------------------+
| st_astext(point(23,56)) |
+-------------------------+
| POINT(23 56)            |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select st_astext(st_srid(point(23,56),3059));
+---------------------------------------+
| st_astext(st_srid(point(23,56),3059)) |
+---------------------------------------+
| POINT(23 56)                          |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

However, if I set the SRID to 4326, the coordinates are swapped:
mysql> select st_astext(st_srid(point(23,56),4326));
+---------------------------------------+
| st_astext(st_srid(point(23,56),4326)) |
+---------------------------------------+
| POINT(56 23)                          |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

What's going on? Setting SRID when unwrapping a serialized point doesn't change the coords:
mysql> select st_astext(st_geomfromwkb(st_asbinary(point(23,56)),4326));
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| st_astext(st_geomfromwkb(st_asbinary(point(23,56)),4326)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| POINT(23 56)                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

So I could use this workaround, but I also want to understand if this is a bug or not.
Btw PostGIS does not swap the coords when doing ST_SetSRID to 4326.

You got an answer on reddit. Did you check that?

Hi, @OPPO can you share it's documentation link ? I'm interesting to learn it

Maybe relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131363/choosing-srid-and-what-is-its-meaning
